# Do Xfinity hotspots require passwords?

Tags: passwords, wifi, hotspot

There's a Xfinity hotspot(xfinitywifi)that I see on my phone that I occasionally use for reasons but lately it has been acting up so I contacted Xfinity customer support. They asked for some stuff including the password for the hotspot. The thing is, the hotspot didn't have a password. Customer support tells me that I need a password to connect but I didn't need one. How is that possible? Additional info: my dad is a Xfinity internet user and the phone doesn't have a carrier but it connects to our router and the hotspot before it started acting up

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  After you connect to the hotspot, you need to open your browser and sign-in using your Xfinity username and password.  See https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/about-xfinity-wifi-internet.